# How to close a SQL Server 2008 transaction?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions

I'm connected to a database in SQL Server 2008, and using a new query window on the database, I run

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

and it shows

```
Replicated Transaction Information:
        Oldest distributed LSN     : (0:0:0)
        Oldest non-distributed LSN : (93627:242:1)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Even when I close the query and a few hours later run the same `DBCC OPENTRAN` command, the results are the same.

I'm assuming that I have an uncommitted transaction. Am I correct? If so, since I am the administrator of this machine, how do I close/commit this transaction?

The log is at 3-4GB and growing by nearly 200MB or more, each day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by the following:

```
Execute SP_ReplicationDbOption Blog2012,Publish,true,1
GO
Execute sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_segno = NULL, @numtrans = 0, @time = 0, @reset = 1
GO
DBCC ShrinkFile(Blog_Log,0)
GO
Execute SP_ReplicationDbOption Blog2012,Publish,false,1
GO
```

where Blog2012 is the database name, and Blog_Log is the name of the log.